# Colimits and $\text{Hom}(-,G)$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, functors, representable-functor

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}$
Let $(A_i)_i$ be an inverse system of groups. If $G$ is a group, then we have a projective system of set $(\Hom (A_i,G))_i$. I would like to understand
$$\colim_i\Hom(A_i,G).$$
Assume that for each $f_i:A_i\rightarrow G$, there exists a $j\geq i$ such that $$A_j\rightarrow A_i\rightarrow G$$
is trivial. Can we conclude that $\colim_i\Hom(A_i,G)$ is a singleton?

Comment: No, there is no reason why that would be the case. $Set$ and $Set^{op}$ are different categories. The statement $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{colim}_i -,-)\simeq \mathrm{lim}_i\mathrm{Hom}( -,-)$ abstractly expresses the universal property of colimits, while there is no such analogous statement in the situation you suggest. To see that it actually does not work, take the inverse system $\mathbb{Z}/2 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}/4 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}/8 \dots$ and try to map it, and its limit $\mathbb{Z}_2$, to something torsion free, such as $\mathbb{Z}_2$ again.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks, I'll change my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this version is correct: the elements of the colimit are the equivalence classes of homomorphisms $\varphi: A_i \rightarrow G$ (for any $i$) under the equivalence $[\varphi]=[\varphi \circ p_{i,j}]$ where $p_{i, j}: A_j \rightarrow A_i$ are the maps from the inverse system.

By your assumption, every homomorphism is thus equivalent to the trivial morphism $A_j \rightarrow G$ for some $j$.

So suppose that $\varphi: A_i \rightarrow G,$ $\psi: A_{i'}\rightarrow G$ are two homomorphisms. By the above, $\varphi$ is equivalent to the trivial map $A_j \rightarrow G$ for some $j$, and $\psi$ is equivalent to the trivial map $A_{j'} \rightarrow G$ for some $j'$. Taking $j'' \geq j, j',$ one can then see that the trivial maps $A_j \rightarrow G, A_{j'}\rightarrow G$ are both equivalent to the trivial map $A_{j''}\rightarrow G$. Thus, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are ultimately equivalent, and the colimit is thus a singleton.